# Angular2 mapping object properties

Tags: angular, typescript

Apologies for this probably super confusing title, I don't know if its exactly accurate with what I am trying to do.

I have a component that is assigning objects of data to variables so that they can be `typecast`. I have interfaces created for this purpose:

```
export interface Role {
    RoleID: number;
    RoleName: string;
}

export interface Language {
    LanguageID: number;
    LanguageName: string;
}


...

roles: Role[] = [];
languages: Language[] = [];
```

I am using an npm module called [ng-select](https://roolebo.github.io/ng2-select-compat/) which adds some extended functionality to select inputs.

My HTML is set up like so:

```
<ng-select 
 [allowClear]="true"
 [items]="roles"
 placeholder="No role selected">
</ng-select>
```

All of my select inputs use an ID (value) and Label (text). This is great because the module allows for that.

> Array of items from which to select. Should be an array of objects with id and text properties.

My question is as follows: The object that this module is wanting is needed the property names to be `id` and `text`. Since I am typing my inputs to the interface though, I am unable to rename them in there.

Are there any suggestions on how I can map this data in a way where I can provide the module my object and say that `RoleID = id` and `RoleName = text` for example.

In short, my current object of:

```
{
    RoleID: 123,
    RoleName: 'Admin'

}
```

Needs to be:

```
{
    id: 123,
    text: 'Admin'

}
```

Comment: what is the question??

Comment: @Aravind - It has been answered, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can bind the `[items]` attribute to a method of the component class that returns an array of transformed objects using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

**HTML:**

```
<ng-select 
 [allowClear]="true"
 [items]="roleItems"
 placeholder="No role selected">
</ng-select>
```

**TS:**

```
roleItems: Role[] = [];

getRoles(): Role[] {
    this.roleItems = this.roles.map((role: Role) => {
        return { id: role.RoleID, text: role.RoleName };
    });
}
```

**Update:** Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3vD6RhO1BFNBwHK9vpqr?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality in action with a simple list and `ngFor`.

Comment: sweet, that looks to be exactly what I need! Will accept shorty, you were too quick on the answer ;)

Comment: It's a bad practice to get roles in template, as it will be called with each change detection. This can potentially destroy your app performance.

Also, why the any type instead of Role[]?.

Comment: @cnps you’re right. I created this answer years ago in a hurry. It was meant to quickly show how to use Array.prototype.map because the OP didn’t provide details on how they load the data needing to be mapped.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yea, I noticed the answer was a couple years old, but should probably be updated, so new people don't think it's a good solution.